# Is MAM encrypted message has perfect secrecy?

Tags: iota-network, security, masked-authenticated-messaging

Here I am referring to MAM in restricted mode, where side key is used to encrypt the message.

One time pad is known for perfect secrecy. Since MAM uses the one-time pad, is MAM encrypted message has perfect secrecy?

In the one-time pad secret key must be the same size as the message. Is MAM side key has the same length as the message?

Comment: I'd like to submit the same question. Precisely, which is the algorithm used to encrypt the payload?